# Converting csv file to KML

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, kml

Im trying to convert my csv file to kml file.
I built a method that received an arraylist.
I dont understand why the kml file im getting isn't running on google earth.

Here is my code :

```
  static void writeFileKML(ArrayList<String[]> a, String output) {
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
    String kmlstart = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">\n";
    content.add(kmlstart);

    String kmlend = "</kml>";
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
            String[] s = a.get(i);
            String kmlelement ="<Placemark>\n" +
                    "<name>"+s[6]+"</name>\n" +
                    "<description>"+s[6]+"</description>\n" +
                    "<Point>\n" +
                    "<coordinates>"+s[3]+","+s[2]+"</coordinates>" +
                    "</Point>\n" +
                    "</Placemark>\n";
            content.add(kmlelement);
        }
        content.add(kmlend);
        String csv = content.toString().replaceAll(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        bw.write(csv);
        bw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The csv the function gets contains multipule wifi networks from different places.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post [mcve]: include short test data (input array list),and what do you expect as output.

Answer (score 0):

A collection of placemarks in KML must be contained within a [Document](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#document) or a Folder parent element not directly inside the `<kml>` element.

Make the outer-most element a `<Document>` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Document>
  <Placemark>...</Placemark>
  <Placemark>...</Placemark>
 </Document>
</kml>
```